# Preseed LVM+Crypto 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lvm, preseed

I cannot get a 18.04 with encrypted LVM, by preseed file, partman says:

> No modifications can be made to the device Encrypted volume
>   (sda5_crypt) for the following reasons: In use by LVM volume group
>   ubuntu-vg

Preseed content:

```
### Partitioning

#d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
#d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-crypto
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string gaming

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
      boot-crypto :: \
              538 538 1075 free \
                    $primary \
                    $iflabel{ gpt } \
                    $reusemethod{ } \
                    method{ efi } format{ } \
              . \
              256 512 256 ext2 \
                    $primary \
                    $defaultignore{ } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 } \
                    label{ boot } \
                    mountpoint{ /boot } \
              . \
              4000 4000 4000 ext4 \
                    $lvmok{ } \
                    lv_name{ root } \
                    in_vg { gaming } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                    label{ root } \
                    mountpoint{ / } \
              . \
              2000 2000 2000 ext4 \
                    $lvmok{ } \
                    lv_name{ home } \
                    in_vg { gaming } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                    label{ home } \
                    mountpoint{ /home } \
              . \
              32000 32000 100% linux-swap \
                    $lvmok{ } \
                    lv_name{ swap } \
                    in_vg { gaming } \
                    method{ swap } format{ } \
              . \
              10000 1000000 10000000 ext4 \
                    $lvmok{ } \
                    $lv_name{ deleteme }  \
                    in_vg { gaming } \
                    method{ format } format{ } \
                    use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
                    mountpoint{ /deleteme } \
              . \
```

What's wrong in my preseed?

Comment: same preseed worked on debian 9 install

Answer (score 0):

maybe syntax error - last dot shouldn't be beside the slash "\"

There is the problem https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644395/debian-preseed-does-not-create-encrypted-disk-with-luks-lvm-properly